# Visual Studio loses track of pending changes after unshelve

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2005

Yesterday I worked on a set of changes I don't want to check in yet, and at the end of the day, decided to shelve my changes. The changes included a bunch of added files. The shelving worked fine, but today when I unshelved, the following happened:

- VS told me four writable files already exist in my workspace. These files were the ones I added
- I told VS it's all good, overwrite them and we're set
- VS finished the unshelve...
- ... but left the "pending changes" tab empty.

I figured maybe something went wrong and re-tried the unshelve. At this point VS proceeded to tell me I've got pending changes in my workspace. So now I can't check in, can't unshelve and apparently the files are locked for edit under my name (yes, we use the lock-modify-unlock mode, unfortunately). What gives, and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** <strike>Upon further inspection, Source Control Explorer *doesn't* show pending changes from me, so apparently it's just my workspace that's borked.</strike> Correction: yes, it does, I was just looking at the wrong branch, aargh!

**Edit 2:** tf.exe *does* show the changes. I tried to undo them, delete the files that were still in the workspace (the ones that caused first VS error) and unshelved without errors. For a short while VS displayed the pending changes, but when the operation completed, they all disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I'm just full of stupid today. The shelveset I was working with didn't belong to the branch I had open. Opening the project from the correct branch miraculously shows the changes in the pending changes tab!